# Not able to access private member through friend function

Tags: c++, friend

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class S;

class R {
        int width, height;
        public:
        int area ()   // Area of rectangle
   {return (width * height);}
    void convert (S a);  
};
class S {
   private:
   int side;
   public:
   S (int a) : side(a) {}
   friend void convert(S a);

};

void R::convert (S a) {    
   width = a.side;
   height = a.side;    // Interpreting Square as an rectangle
}
int main () {

   int x;

   cin >> x;
   R rect;
   S sqr (x);
   rect.convert(sqr);
   cout << rect.area();
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

> prog.cpp: In member function ‘void R::convert(S)’: prog.cpp:26:14:
>   error: ‘int S::side’ is private within this context
>       width = a.side;
>                 ^~~~ prog.cpp:16:8: note: declared private here
>       int side;
>           ^~~~ prog.cpp:27:15: error: ‘int S::side’ is private within this context
>       height = a.side;    // Interpreting Square as an rectangle
>                  ^~~~ prog.cpp:16:8: note: declared private here
>       int side;
>           ^~~~

I tried putting the friend function function private also but same error.
Please help

Comment: friend is in S class not in R ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `class S` you should have `friend R;`

`friend void convert(S a);` is meaningless because the compiler doesn't even know convert belongs to R not S.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

For starters the name `S` is not declared before it is first used in the declaration

```
void convert ( S a);
```

And secondly you have to specify that the function `convert` is a member function of the class `R`.

Try the following

```
class R {
        int width, height;
        public:
        int area ()   // Area of rectangle
   {return (width * height);}
    void convert ( class S a);  
                   ^^^^^^
};
class S {
   private:
   int side;
   public:
   S (int a) : side(a) {}
   friend void R::convert(S a);
              ^^^ 
};
```